# How to resize a large full page table to fit in the page?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, floats, formatting, resize

I am working on a table to show the question-answer examples, The code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{0,255,0}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label*=\alph*),
                  font=\bfseries,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  nosep,
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
                  after=\end{minipage}}

\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\newcommand{\correctitem}{\item[\stepcounter{tabenumi}\colorbox{mygreen}{\thetabenumi}]}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\footnotesize
\caption{Examples}
\label{tab:subject_wise}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ccX}
\toprule
 \thead{Question\\ Type} & \thead{Percent.} & \thead{Example} \\
\midrule
Type 1  &  0.47 & Which is not a side effect of the progestogen-only pill (POP)?  \\
        &       & \begin{tabenum}
                  \correctitem Ovarian cysts
                  \item  Venous thromboembolism
                  \item  Increased risk of diabetes mellitus 
                  \item  Ectopic pregnancy
                  \end{tabenum}
 \\
\midrule
Type 1  &  0.47 & Which is not a side effect of the progestogen-only pill (POP)? Ths question is a lot longer, this question is a lot longer \\
        &       & \begin{tabenum}
                  \correctitem Ovarian cysts
                  \item  Venous thromboembolism
                  \item  Increased risk of diabetes mellitus 
                  \item  Ectopic pregnancy
                  \end{tabenum}
 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Showing like this:

[image]

If I am adding more questions it's going out of page length limit and showing a warning

[image]

[image]

How to resize this table to fit on one page?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? If you put more stuff on a page than there is room for, it will overflow. Do you expect that the table (and the font size) shrinks when the table gets larger, or do you expect that the table breaks at the page end and continues on the next page? In the latter case, check out the `longtable` package.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me: is the table too long for the page height or too wide for the page width?

Comment: Is I already showed you in your previous question, you could use a inline `enumerate` style to save a lot of space here. (To do so, use `\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate*}{1}` instead of `\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}`.) Alternatively, you could use the `xltabular` package to keep the `X` type column while at the same time allowing the table to spread across pages.